# How to get data from didReceiveRemoteNotification return data?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, notifications

Running on xcode8 with swift3

Below is my code from AppDelegate.swift

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    print("==== didReceiveRemoteNotification ====")
    print(userInfo)
}
```

When I get a notification and click on it, my debug area will how like below

```
==== didReceiveRemoteNotification ====
[AnyHashable("type"): order, AnyHashable("aps"): {
    alert = "[TestMessage]";
    badge = "<null>";
    category = alert;
    sound = default;
}, AnyHashable("url"): http://www.google.com]
```

My question is how can I use userInfo to get data from AnyHashable("url") which is "www.google.com" ?

I try

```
print(userInfo[AnyHashable("url")])
```

but output in debug area is

```
Optional(http://www.google.com)
```

Comment: Please check update answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if let url = userInfo["url"] as? String {
    //do whatever you need with the url
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try `print(userInfo[AnyHashable("url")] as? String ?? "")` Or you can cast it as `URL`

Answer (score 2):

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    if let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? NSDictionary {
        print(aps)
        let alert = (aps.object(forKey: "alert") as? String)!
    }

    let url = userInfo?["url"] as? String {
        print(url)
    }
}
```